# How should I get Scrapy to loop over pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get some reviews from Amazon for a product. This code below scrapes the first page and then continues looping over it, doesn't move to the next page. I scraped over 20 pages but got reviews from the first page repeated 20 times. How should I fix this?

```
import scrapy

class AmazonReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

# Spider name
name = 'amazon_reviews'

# Domain names to scrape
allowed_domains = ['amazon.in']

myBaseUrl = "https://www.amazon.in/Maggi-2-Minute-Noodles-Masala-Pack/product-reviews/B07B4KQRZG/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&amp;amp;pageNumber="

start_urls=[]

# List of urls to be scraped 
for i in range(1,20):
    start_urls.append(myBaseUrl+str(i))
#print (start_urls)

# Scrapy parser
def parse(self, response):
        data = response.css('#cm_cr-review_list')

        # Collecting product star ratings
        star_rating = data.css('.review-rating')

        # Collecting user reviews
        comments = data.css('.review-text')
    
        #Collecting review date
        review_date = data.css('.review-date')
        
        count = 0

        for c in comments:
            yield{'comments':''.join(c.xpath('.//text()').extract()),
                  'stars': ''.join(star_rating[count].xpath('.//text()').extract()),
                  'date': ''.join(review_date[count].xpath(".//text()").extract())
                 }
            count=count+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `&` instead of `;amp;`:

```
myBaseUrl = "https://www.amazon.in/Maggi-2-Minute-Noodles-Masala-Pack/product-reviews/B07B4KQRZG/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&amp&pageNumber="
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it.